# Development Isolation branch strategy: Origin for branching?

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging, azure-devops, branching-strategy

We have two branches; **Development** (whereby developers regularly check/integrate into) and **Main** (where code from Development is merged into for versioning/releasing).

When reading about branching "strategies"/"best practices", it is said that **Development** must be a *branch of* **Main**.  **Development** must be *branched from* **Main**.

For example, when reading about Development Isolation in the VS ALM Ranger's [Branching Strategies document](https://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/downloads/get/801996), it says how *"the development branch should be a full child branch of the main branch"*.

Why can't **Main** be a full branch from **Development**?  From how I understand, **Development** will almost always contain everything (excluding hotfixes) that **Main** has.

Merging from **Development** to **Main** is the more common scenario. Does it even matter in this case which is the "original" and which is the branch?

Note: We are using Visual Studio Team Services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all of my experiences with using TFS we use the following schema:

-**Main Branch** (This branch will reflect the current deployed code)

--**Staging Branch** (This branch will act as a testing environment for QA. This can be removed if it doesn't make sense in your case.)

---**Development Branch** (This is the branch that the developers will be checking into regularly.)

---

Our reasoning behind this setup is that the **main branch** will reflect the current deployed code on the server. This way if we do need to do a hot fix it can be completely isolated from the current development cycle so nothing we are working on will sneak into the fix.

The **staging branch** will be essentially where your QA department will perform its validation. Some organizations handle this differently so this might not apply to your situation.

The **development branch** will be the most "experimental" branch. This has the highest potential for having bugs and general developer shenanigans. We place this branch around the bottom because if a developer finds him/herself needing to create a branch off the development branch for any reason the flow of information will make sense. Merge up to push changes, and merge down to get the updated changes.

I stumbled upon this post that has a much better explanation on the best merge practices. This should answer any confusion I introduced (:

[TFS: Merge best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860736/tfs-merge-best-practices)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  My questions is more about WHY Development needs to be branched off from Main and not the other way around?  How does this make a difference from a merging perspective?

Comment: I think you'll get a better idea if you review the link on best merge practices but let's say you want to add another branch from your current parent branch (**development**). By adding the branch (**Staging** for example) you will now have **Development** as the parent of both **main** and your **staging** branches. This creates an issue if you want to merge to **staging** for testing, then merge the **staging** branch to the **main** branch for deployment while continuing your development cycle. The direction (or Flow) of changes is what we need to look at here.