# HowTo: correctly synchronize TFS branches with missing changesets?

Tags: tfs, version-control, tfs-2015

### Background

If I *merge* our `main` branch to our `development` branch, TFS will state that there are no changes to commit.  And yet, a file level comparison (using [WinMerge](https://www.visualstudio.com/da-dk/docs/tfvc/merge-command)) clearly shows that there are differences (e.g. files missing, files with different content, etc.).

In short, our `main` and `development` branches are no longer in sync which is most likely due to changesets that were lost during previous TFS migrations.

### Question

What is the best way to produce the following?

1. Synchronizing the `main` and `development` branches by: performing all of the necessary insert/update/delete operations on the `development` branch. (i.e. `main` is the master copy).

   - At the end of the process *WinMerge* should indicate that there are zero (0) differences between the two branches.
2. Keeping the `development` branch history intact.
3. Notifying TFS that the `development` branch is now fully synchronized with `main` so that:

   - TFS won't try to *merge* older `development` changesets with `main`
   - only future changes to `development` will be pushed to `main` during a *merge* operation.

TFS is not my area of expertise - any guidance that you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

### Context

- Visual Studio 2015
- TFS (version 14.95.25122)

### References

- [Merge Command](https://www.visualstudio.com/da-dk/docs/tfvc/merge-command)

  - *"Performs a merge without a base version. That is, allows the user to merge files and folders that do not have a merge relationship. After a baseless merge, a merge relationship exists, and future merges do not have to be baseless."*

    - Although `Development` was branched from `Main`, it looks like this might address my lack of history (i.e. missing changesets) problem.
- [TFS Merge: Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860736/tfs-merge-best-practices/1863984#1863984)
- [TFS: Overwrite a branch with another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2094439/949681)

  - `tf merge A B -r -force -version:T`

    - I don't think this will work for us because changesets are missing.

Comment: File difference exist does not means that there is change can be merge from main to development. What's the result if you run "tf merge /candidate /recursive main development" and "tf merge /candidate /recursive development main" command?

Answer (score 0):

When TFS does a merge, it bases the merge on prior merge history, not on the actual contents of the source and target files.

This issue may by caused by picking `keep target` when perform merge or at one time, a merge with the `discard` option performed (using the command line `TF merge /discard`).

To solve this issue, you can try to:

1. Use the `/force` option with the tf merge command. If there is a changeset that was previously merged (perhaps incorrectly) and you want to merge it again. The /force flag ignores merge history that indicates a particular changeset was previously merged from source to target, and merges the changeset again.
2. Undo the previous merge using Rollback. If you've recently done the merge in which changesets have been discarded. Find it in the history, rightclick the changeset and pick Rollback and check in the code that has been undone.

Comment: re: Cece's comment: _"The /force flag ignores merge history that indicates a particular changeset was previously merged from source to target, and merges the changeset again."_.  This doesn't help because of how my employer migrated from TFS2012 to TFS2013.  Long story short, I **cannot merge based on changesets** because the history is incomplete (i.e. changesets are missing)

Comment: Since you have changesets missing, how about creating a new branch?

Comment: Two development branches would be awkward: to view a file's history you would have to look in two places.  And deleting the old branch would result in the changeset history being lost.

Comment: How about using Rollback?